# how to start a AWS Personalize project in Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize, aws-sdk-java

Can someone help with getting starting using the AWS Java SDK for Personalize?  I used to the console to build a Campaign.  Now I want to query for recommendations using Java.

Amazon has many examples in Python, but I need Java.  Starting with the client builder is especially useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To query for recommendations by using Java V2, you use the **PersonalizeRuntimeClient** object.

Here is an example that uses Java V2. We will have the full examples posted in Java V2 Github very soon.

**

```
package com.example.personalize;
//snippet-start:[personalize.java2.get_recommendations.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.exception.AwsServiceException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.personalizeruntime.PersonalizeRuntimeClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.personalizeruntime.model.GetRecommendationsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.personalizeruntime.model.GetRecommendationsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.personalizeruntime.model.PredictedItem;
import java.util.List;
//snippet-end:[personalize.java2.get_recommendations.import]
public class GetRecommendations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    GetRecommendations <campaignArn> <userId>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    campaignArn - The ARN of the campaign.\n\n" +
                "    userId - The user ID to provide recommendations for\n\n";
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        /* Read the name from command args */
        String campaignArn = args[0];
        String userId = args[1];
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        PersonalizeRuntimeClient personalizeRuntimeClient = PersonalizeRuntimeClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();
        getRecs(personalizeRuntimeClient, campaignArn, userId);
    }
    //snippet-start:[personalize.java2.get_recommendations.main]
    public static void getRecs(PersonalizeRuntimeClient personalizeRuntimeClient, String campaignArn, String userId){
        try {
            GetRecommendationsRequest recommendationsRequest = GetRecommendationsRequest.builder()
                .campaignArn(campaignArn)
                .numResults(20)
                .userId(userId)
                .build();
            GetRecommendationsResponse recommendationsResponse = personalizeRuntimeClient.getRecommendations(recommendationsRequest);
            List<PredictedItem> items = recommendationsResponse.itemList();
            for (PredictedItem item: items) {
                System.out.println("Item Id is : "+item.itemId());
                System.out.println("Item score is : "+item.score());
            }
        } catch (AwsServiceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    //snippet-end:[personalize.java2.get_recommendations.main]
}
```

**

Comment: Github examples are located here - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/personalize